# Are questions about sports broadcasting on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

What questions related to sports broadcasting are on topic?

Some examples

- Who called x game (should be sufficiently obscure)
- What is the proper way to call a curling match (I dunno, technique etc though)
- How do you maintain neutrality when you call games for one team all year

These are obviously slightly silly proposal questions, but the overall idea is, how much of the media coverage surrounding sports is on topic?

Comment: Question on sports broadcasting: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1890/how-do-soccer-broadcasts-make-money

Answer (score 6):

I think they absolutely should be.  Who called games, how to keep score etc... certainly fall into the scope of sports and are an important way of how we experience sports.

Answer (score 2):

With the London Olympics in full-swing, I feel that sports media (broadcasting, social, etc.) is on-topic (especially if relevant to the nature of a sporting event in-game). I don't feel media about Tiger Woods's sex scandal is on topic.....regardless if it contributed to his poor play. However, I feel media about Jerry Sandusky's underage sex scandal in terms of the PSU football program is on topic as it is relevant to how PSU competes the next four years due to [penalties handed down by the NCAA](http://espn.go.com/college-football/story/_/id/8191027/penn-state-nittany-lions-hit-60-million-fine-4-year-bowl-ban-wins-dating-1998).

Sports broadcasting alone moves the needle of fans' perspectives.

How sports media has affected participants of sports:

- Major sports leagues have implemented [social media guidelines](http://espn.go.com/espn/page2/story/_/id/7026246/examining-sports-leagues-social-media-policies-offenders).
- Olympians [Michel Morganella](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2181214/Olympic-football-2012-Michel-Morganella-sent-home-disgrace-calling-South-Koreans-mongoloids-Twitter.html) and [Paraskevi Papachristou](http://edition.cnn.com/2012/07/25/world/europe/greece-athlete-apology/index.html) have been expelled from their respective Olympic teams due to offensive tweets.

How sports media is relevant from a rules perspective:

- [Media timeouts are written into NCAA rules](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/306/skip-a-media-timeout-in-ncaa-basketball).
- Because of (published) media about Armando Galarraga's ["near-perfect" game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armando_Galarraga%27s_near-perfect_game), the MLB put a rule into effect that Jim Joyce (the umpire who incorrectly called a runner safe, costing Galarraga a perfect game) cannot umpire any games in which Galarraga’s team plays because they are business partners. Their business relationship could affect Joyce's impartiality while umpiring Galarraga's team.