# Media: Are announcer/commentator identification questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We have decided that sports broadcasting is [on-topic](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138/are-questions-about-sports-broadcasting-on-topic) on Sports SE.

We have had two questions regarding broadcast announcer/commentator identification:

- [Who is this particular English Premiership (Rugby Union) lead announcer?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4779/who-is-this-particular-english-premiership-rugby-union-lead-announcer)
- [What is the name of a guy who comment highlights in NBA](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/what-is-the-name-of-a-guy-who-comment-highlights-in-nba?rq=1)

Both questions are asking who the broadcast announcer/commentator in each respective question is. However, one question has close votes and the other has up-votes. The inconsistency stands out.

The close reason chosen for these votes is, "unclear what is being asked." I believe it is clear what is being asked. A more justified close reason would be "[request for sources/research](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" but this may not capture the nature of the question.

**Are broadcast announcer/commentator identification questions on-topic?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. They are quite on topic.

But they need to show more effort at trying to identify the broadcaster on one's own rather than slapping up a couple of links and asking someone to identify the voice.

Questions like that can be asked, but they should include no less than a paragraph of text explaining *why* they are having trouble identifying the voice. Also it might not hurt to also tell us *why* you want to know.

Comment: -1; for reasons mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

You missed out on this question: **[Commentator IBF events](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3252/1455)**.

As it currently stands, it has 750 views and is the third highest viewed question that I asked. It doesn't really fit the standard @waxeagle describes, yet it has drawn some attention.

Why should/would I explain to the world, why I want to know the person behind a voice? Simply because I want to know. It bothers people not knowing !!

Comment: Yes, I did miss this. However, I was more intent on portraying the inconsistent treatment between the questions I link above, but asking about its usefulness on this site has brought upon a pleasant surprise. We can see more of these types of questions come up. This post was to draw attention to this inconsistency (ie, an upvote or favorable comment leads to more upvotes/favor and vice-versa) and figure out a solution that would allow these questions to be on-topic on Sports SE.

Comment: Looking at your question, you provide adequate background: "I've watched many badminton games on YouTube...I would like to know the name of the female commentator who provided the commentary to many events. [Here she is.]" And waxeagle says, "it might not hurt to also tell us why." I think your question provides more effort by providing a background rather "than slapping up a couple of links."